# NodeJS & Express & socket.io Error: Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I've found this script for reading a file an "broadcast" its content to every connection.

```
var serverServiceConfig={port: 8081}; 

var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var socket = require('socket.io');

function readTick(ws){
  fs.readFile('tick.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (!err) {
          try {
              ws.emit('ticks', data); 
          } catch (e) {
              // handle error
              console.log('can not read file');
          }        
        }
  }); 

  setTimeout(function () {
        readTick(ws);

  }, 200);
}
console.log('server is running ...');
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
});
var server = app.listen(serverServiceConfig.port);
var io = socket.listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        readTick(socket);        
        socket.on('disconnect', function (socket) {
     });
});
```

The server starts without an error, so far so good. But if i try to connect to the server via ip:port i get the following message:

> Cannot GET /

I tested this script on my local machine and it worked (a couple of weeks ago)
From what i "know" or i think is that a route is missing, or?

Any help is more than welcome.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't see a route for "/". Hence the error

Comment: But it worked a couple of months ago. What route if have to add? And how?

Comment: in app.js, there should be something like 

app.get('/', function() { //whatever you are doing here});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using that function, you should put it in app.get('/', function(){//whatever you want to do//})